# match across more than one variable in a data.frame

Tags: r, match

Take some simple data

```
A <- 1:10
B <- 100:109
C <- 222:231
df1 <- data.frame(A,B,C)
df1$Z <- 1:length(A)

D <- c(2,3,4,6)
E <- c(101,202,104,105)
Ff <- c(223,999,225,227)
df2 <- data.frame(D,E,Ff)
```

Now I want to create `df2$Z` which assigns the df1$D value when A==D and B==E and C==Ff, otherwise apply an NA

I try this code, but have incorrect syntax:

```
df2$Z <- df1$Z[match(df1$A & df2$D & df1$B & df2$E & df1$C & df2$Ff)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table` I would do something like

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df2))[df1, Z := i.Z]
df2
#    D   E  Ff  Z
# 1: 2 101 223  2
# 2: 3 202 999 NA
# 3: 4 104 225 NA
# 4: 6 105 227  6
```

Note that we've not set key columns on `df1`, therefore the join is performed between key columns of `df2` and the first 3 columns of `df1` (i.e., by position). If the column order isn't always guaranteed, then set key on `df1` on corresponding columns as well.

---

Another approach altogether that doesn't require setting key (which requires reordering the data.tables which is not always desirable) is to use the newly implemented `on=` argument (available on the latest version on CRAN - v 1.9.6):

```
library(data.table) # V 1.9.6+
setDT(df2)[df1, Z := i.Z, on = c(D = "A", E = "B", Ff = "C")]
df2
#    D   E  Ff  Z
# 1: 2 101 223  2
# 2: 3 202 999 NA
# 3: 4 104 225 NA
# 4: 6 105 227  6
```

Answer (score 1):

That's easy with a left join

```
library(dplyr)
final <- df2 %>% 
  left_join(df1, by = c("D" = "A", "E" = "B", "Ff" = "C")) %>% 
  select(-D, D = D.y)
```

`tmp` will contain `D` which comes from the original `df2` and `D.y` which comes from `df1`. `select(-D)` removes `D`, `select(D = D.y)` renames `D.y` to `D`. `select(-D, D = D.y)` first removes `D` and then `D.y` to `D`, giving the required result.

```
tmp <- df2 %>% 
  left_join(df1, by = c("D" = "A", "E" = "B", "Ff" = "C"))
```

Comment: can you please update, I noticed 2x D in the answer, so i changed one to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1):

Base `R` you can do - columns need to be in the same order:

```
x = apply(df2,1,paste0, collapse='')
y = apply(df1[1:3],1, paste0, collapse='')

df2$Z = df1$Z[match(x,y)]

#  D   E  Ff  Z
#1 2 101 223  2
#2 3 202 999 NA
#3 4 104 225 NA
#4 6 105 227  6
```